# Error indexing a NumPy image array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, indexing

I've written a program using Python 2.7, Numpy and OpenCV to grab a photo from my webcam and give the rgb value of every pixel.  After running the code on a 640x480 pixel photo:

```
for x in range(638):
    for y in range(478):
        red, green, blue = image[x, y]
        print(red, green, blue)
```

I get the error message:

```
red, green, blue = image[x, y]
IndexError: index 480 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 480
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: 480 is from 0 to 479.

Comment: yes I know, tried that

Comment: it's [y,x] in numpy and opencv. also, please, **never** iterate over pixels like that, it's horrible slow, error-prone, and totally defeats the purpose of a high-level library

Comment: btw, pixel order is b g r, not r g b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is a 640 x 480 image has shape `(480, 640, n_channels)`. If you change your code to `image[y, x]` you will not get this error. It might be easier to understand if you write the code as:

```
for row in range(image.shape[0]):
    for col in range(image.shape[1]):
      r, g, b = image[row, col]
```

Here's a tutorial on [indexing image data](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html) which shows you how to do a few operations efficiently and has some details on indexing conventions.